# How to find maximum group size dynamically

Tags: python, logic, partitioning, partition

I want to find the maximum group size `g_new` if I want to partition a list of 'n' values. We can have any number of groups.

I have:
`n` values and maximum group size possible `g_max`.

e.g.

`n = 110` and `g_max = 25`.

We cannot form groups of size: `[28,28,27,27]` as no group should be more than 25!

Here, Solution is, `g_new` can be 22. as it will form 5 groups of 22 each.

My question is:

How can I find dynamically, this `g_new` (22 here) value, given : `n` and `g_max`

Note that I want to form biggest possible groups without violating `g_max`!

Sorry, if this question is too simple, but I cannot get my head around it.

Comment: your question is incredibly confusing. Can you please provide sample input and expected output from a very easy example with low numbers?

Comment: 5 * 22 > 100. I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry if I was not able to convey the problem statement correctly. It might be my non-native english speaker thing. But, thanks @KellyBundy for answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant n=110 and want group sizes to differ by at most 1, you could first compute the up-rounded number of needed groups and then the up-rounded group size:

```
>>> n, g_max = 110, 25
>>> -(n // (-n // g_max))
22
```

```
>>> n, g_max = 110, 36
>>> -(n // (-n // g_max))
28
```

Comment: This is code is beautiful and hits the  hammer on the nail. This is exactly, what was needed..! I am seeing this trick in python first time and love it after seeing it here. Thanks!